# Assign arguments to List

Tags: c#, linq

I have put together the following method:

```
public static bool compareTableRow(List<string> expected,  int rowNumberOfElemets, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        List<string> actual = new List<string>
        { };

        for (int i = 1; i < rowNumberOfElemets + 1; i++)
        {
            actual.Add(driver.FindElementHighlight
              (By.XPath("//*[@id=\"nefi-content\"]/div[2]/section/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[" + i + "]/div/input")).GetAttribute("value"));
        }

        if (expected.SequenceEqual(actual)) return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

At the moment the 'expected' List is hard-coded. What kind of method variable should I put as an input to be able to call the method and **pass** the strings I'm trying to compare ("bla1","123", "bla2", "etc", "etc") ?

Comment: `List<string>`? Note that the first parameter currently doesn't have a name. Make that `expected` and remove the declaration of `expected` inside the method.

Comment: Opps, made the change @Sweeper..How should I change the inside of the method ?

Comment: @entrup - `List<string> expected` isn't hard-coded. You're passing it as a parameter. You can set it to whatever you like at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with your implementation you dont need to hardcode the `expected` argument, it is easy to call your method like this:

```
compareTableRow(new List<string> {"bla1", "123", "bla2", "etc", "etc"}, 42, driver);
```

Alternatively, you can use `params` keyword (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params):

```
public static bool compareTableRow(int rowNumberOfElemets, IWebDriver driver, params string[] expected)
{
    ...
}
```

and call it like you described:

```
compareTableRow(42, driver, "bla1", "123", "bla2", "etc", "etc");
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an `IWebDriver`, which has a notion of a number of rows. You also have an input `rowNumberOfElements` and a list of expected strings.

You want to check if the first `rowNumberOfElements` items that you can `FindByElementHighlight` from the `IWebDriver` is exactly equal to the list of expected strings.

I see several issues here:

First of all: is the order in the list of expected strings important? So should the first expected string equal the first `FindByElementHighLight`? According to your code the order is important.

Furthermore: is the list of expected strings long enough? Can it be longer than `rowNumberElements`, or is it normally exactly long enough, and can you replace the `rowNumberElements` with the number of elements in the expected list?

If the first element does not match, you know it's useless to check the other elements, because you already know that the return value will be false.

**A generic solution**

I'll use this to write it as an extension method of IWebDriver. It will be as if you ask the IWebDriver: do the first X elements of you equal the first X elements of this sequence? See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static bool HasExpectedHighLights(this IWebDriver driver, ICollection<string> expected)
{
      // TODO: driver == null? expected == null?
      return driver.HasExpectedHighLights(expected, expected.Count);
}
static bool HasExpectedHighLights(this IWebDriver driver,
   IEnumerable<string> expected, int nrOfElements)
{
    // TODO: driver == null? expected == null? nrOfElements < 0?
    your code goes here
}
```

First we'll show the usage:

```
List<string> expectedHighLights = ...
IWebDriver driver = ...
var isExpected = driver.HasExpectedHighLights(expectedHighLights);
```

But is will also work in the middle of some LINQ statement:

```
IEnumerable<image> images = ...
var imagesWithExpectedHighLights = images
    .Where(image => image.Driver.HasExpectedHighLights(expectedHighLights))
    .Slect(image => ...);
```

So now the code. The most important part is that we should stop as soon as you can.

```
static string FindElementHighLight(this IWebDriver driver, int i)
{
     return driver.FindElementHighlight(By.XPath("//*[@id=\" ... etc);
}

static bool HasExpectedHighLights(this IWebDriver driver,
   IEnumerable<string> expected, int nrOfElements)
{
    // TODO: exception if driver == null? expected == null? nrOfElements < 0?

    IEnumerable<string> actualHighLights = driver
        .Select( (driver,  i) => driver.FindElementHighLight(i)
        .Take(nrOfElements);
    // note: this has only created the enumerable.
    // The sequence has not been enumerated yet

    return actualHighLights.SequenceEqual(expected);
    // sequence equal will stop as soon as a mismatch has been found      
}
```

So if you find a mismatch at i == 3, then HighLight(4) is not calculated.

The nice thing is that without changing your IWebDriver, you have added functionality to it: FindElementHighLight(int).

This can be used to create the IEnumerable in SequenceEqual, which prevents having to fetch all highlights, even if you detected that the first highlight was not as expected.